# How to build a shared library in ubuntu 22.04 that can be used under ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, ubuntu

How to build a shared  library I have a work computer with ubuntu 20.04 and a development computer with ubuntu 22.04. Normally I would compile a .so and .a file on the development computer and use it on the work computer. The .so file from ubuntu 20.04 is usually named XX_20.04.so XX_20.04.a, while ubuntu 22.04 is XX_22.04.so XX_22.04.a.
I want to know if I can build the same .so & .a file on ubuntu 22.04 as on ubuntu 20.04.in ubuntu 22.04 that can be used under ubuntu 20.04. all code is c.

Since the work software on my work computer can no longer be modified, I hope it is best to have something like a 20.04 build.so & .a file in ubuntu 22.04, so that the build is exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a program running on a different version of the operating system that is used to develop the program you need to acquire the needed libraries of the program when running in the target system, as part of the development system you are using to build.  The reason, very simple: Each library has a list of symbols it provides establishing some interface and this can be different of the ones running in the target system.

To cope with this, the ELF binary format uses a field, specified normaly at build time of the library, that specifies the so called `soname` of the library.  This is a label that the dynamic loader uses to select the file to load at run time, and normally is written as some truncation of the actual library version number (excluding the part of the version that doesn't change the actual interface exported by the library)

So, for example, let's say that I have a system in which `/usr/lib/libc.so` (I will use the name used by the compiler to specify the linker which library has to be linked into the program) is a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/libc.so.1.3`, which in turn is a link to `/usr/lib/libc.so.1.4.65`.

- The last name `/usr/lib/libc.so.1.4.65` is the actual name and version of the `libc` library running on your system (actual names I have invented, so version numbers don't have to match your system)  and **you have to install normally only one of these** to be the system library to use (we'll see below how this is done)
- The middle name `/usr/lib/libc.so.1.4` is the file named after the soname specified to refer to all the compatible versions of the library (this name will be used on linking to select which library version is neede by the programs linking to it)
- The first name `/usr/lib/libc.so` is the development file used by the compiler when calling the linker `ld(1)` to link against the library.

### How is the selection done.

When the program is loaded in memory, there's a special module `/lib/ld.so` (I don't remember the exact name) that is always fixed in the system, and is required to be linked into the executable to load and link all the other libraries.  If you specify `-static` at compile/link time, then that file is not used, and so, no dynamic loading of libraries can be done, so if you specify a dynamic library to link to, the linker will fail with an error.

In Linux, the `ld.so` binary is in charge to search all the libraries registered in the system (it uses this by using the `soname` as specified in the binary executable) and consults a database (which has been built from a configuratio file, normally specified as `/etc/ld-so.conf`)  that is created at boot time, to locate in a set of specified directories, for ELF files which have a defined `soname`, it then creates a symbolic link from the library file, in that same directory, but with the `soname` as name, and registers in the database a map between the soname and the actual file found.  The database allows for quick search of the library versioned file, and speeds loading of libraries based on this cache.

If the file is not found in the cache, a search is made in the list of directories with the `soname` specified in the ELF executable to allow to locate a file.  As the program `ldconf(8)` (this is the program used to builld the cache and the symbolic links) is executed, your library will be found as correctly registered.

### Troubleshooting

If your system is unable to load some library, you can use `ldd(1)` to make `ld-so` to find all the libraries and do the work, printing all the sonames found in the files, and the final library files that are found in the system
to load.  If some appears as `unknown`, this means that the library has not been found.  Reasons can be:

1. You have not put the library in one of the directories (or the directory in which you want it is not in the file `/etc/ld-so.conf`)
2. You have not built the cache, after installing your file there.  You must run `ldconfig(8)` as root for the cache to be rebuilt.
3. You have not defined a `soname` for your library, so no entry is included in the cache.

If you do install the libraries that differ in soname in your development system, and make, e.g. for library `mylib`)  an entry as `/usr/lib/libmylib.so -> /usr/lib/libmylib.so.1` (the soname) and
`/usr/lib/libmylib.so -> /usr/lib/libmylib.so.1.35` (the library version in your target system, you will be able to develop programs using `-lmylib` as a linker option in your build)  But be careful and do this only with the libraries that differ in your development system, or you will be changing your development system with the libraries of your execution target system.